# Twig same as operator

Tags: php, twig, comparison-operators

When comparing in PHP, it is advisable to use `===` instead of `==` due to intransitive nature and quirks like `"5 is not a number" == 5`.

By that guideline, does it mean that the [`same as`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/sameas.html) operator should be used instead of `==` in Twig?:

```
{# "Wrong" #}
{% if foo.bar == 3 %}

{# Better #}
{% if foo.bar is same as(3) %}
```

And likewise for `is not same as` versus `!=`.

Comment: Not sure to understand your question. == and === are both correct depending of what you are trying to compare. That depend what you want the condition return after the elements type juggling.

Comment: @YoannAugen I've never had a case where I want the elements to be type juggled (or converted to numbers) to compare equality, at least not in PHP. See http://phpsadness.com/sad/47

Comment: and if you want to compare true with 1 ?

Comment: @YoannAugen If I wanted to determine truthiness of a value I'd just do `{% if foo %}`

Comment: If for a "strange" reason you want execute something comparing 2 variable and want it's true when one contain 1 and the other contain true. You will need a ==. It's true than most of time === will be better than == so twig "is same" too, but I don't think you can assume that it will be always the case. I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense when treating PHP and Twig as two very different tools. Fabien Potencier's main motive for creating Twig was to provide a tool for *Web Designers, not Web Developers*. (See his [blog post for more insight](http://fabien.potencier.org/templating-engines-in-php.html)).

Web developers should know to be more explicit and use `===` as often as possible. In the realm of web design this is perhaps not as vital, but if needed, that feature is available as `same as()` in Twig.